# Firebase Admin SDK timing out in 'getServerSideProps' Vercel

Tags: firebase, next.js, firebase-admin, vercel

I want to use the SEO features that come with Next.JS, but I've been rendering the video information client side for the time being.  I'd like to start using server side rendering (to use OpenGraph protocol mostly), but this getServerSide props function has been running for over 20s per load when I host locally with `npm run dev` and when I deploy to vercel, it times out the serverless function. Is there something I'm forgetting to do with the Firebase Admin SDK that might make it finish faster? I'm wondering if it takes a long time to initialize the app on each load.

firebaseAdmin.ts:

```
import admin from "firebase-admin";

if (!admin.apps.length) {
    admin.initializeApp({
        projectId: 'PROJECT_ID',
        credential: admin.credential.cert({
            projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
            privateKey: process.env.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY.replace(/\\n/g, '\n'),
            clientEmail: process.env.FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL
          }),
    });
}


export {admin};
```

videoPage.tsx

```
import {admin} from './firebaseAdmin.ts'

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (ctx) => {
    const {video} = ctx.params;
    const snapshot = await admin.firestore(app).doc('/videos/'+video).get();
    const data = snapshot.data();
    if (data.private) return { props: {} };
    return {
        props: {
            title: data.title,
            image: data.images[0].image
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am facing the exact same issues :(

Comment: I didn't @DanielReiling. I had to stick to CSR for the time being until Next 13 becomes stable.